# How to store only certain number of document versions in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume I would like to track computers on my network storing information about mac-address with the device name, port name, vlan number and timestamp.
I could grab mac-address-table from all switches in regular intervals, parse it and dump that data into mongodb.

The problem is: how to STORE only last 100 unique entries for each mac-address.

Capped collections is no-go, because to do that I would have to create separate collection for each mac, which is bad idea.

The number of switches and mac-addresses may change over time, and new data might be inserted at irregular intervals.

The other idea I have is to write some query which looks for the timestamp of 100th oldest entry for each mac-address and remove all older entries, and run this queries after each batch of inserts. It may work, but doesn't seem very efficient.

Do you have any better ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... found something interesting:

how about storing each version in an array using $push operator with $slice modifier?

there are some examples in the docs:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/

Comment: right, that's it. sorry I missed this. I incorporated that into my answer so it's a little more complete for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

> The other idea I have is to write some query which looks for the timestamp of 100th oldest entry for each mac-address and remove all older entries, and run this queries after each batch of inserts. It may work, but doesn't seem very efficient.

That sounds good to me. It might be cleaner to use cyclic buffer for this:

```
{
   mac : "AA:AA:AA:AA:AA",
   entryPointer : 2, // pointer of the next entry to be written
   lastEntries : [
      { "ip" : "127.0.0.1", "service" : "foo", ts : ISODate(...), ... }, 
      { "ip" : "127.0.0.1", "service" : "foo", ts : ISODate(...), ... }, 
      { "ip" : "255.255.255.255", "service" : "longestProbableServiceName",
        ts : ISODate(0001-01-01), ... }
      ...
      { "ip" : "255.255.255.255", "service" : "longestProbableServiceName",
        ts : ISODate(0001-01-01), ... }
   ]
}
```

An update would have to increase the pointer and overwrite the position in the array given by pointer % 100. It will be helpful to preallocate the memory in the array as demonstrated to avoid fragmentation and reallocation overhead.

As you pointed out, the modulo-update can be done using [`$slice` and `$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#slice-from-the-end-of-the-array):

```
db.foo.update(
   { mac : "AA:AA:AA..." },
   {
     $push: {
       lastEntries : {
         $each: [ { "ip" : "012.002.003.012", ... } ],
         $slice: -100
       }
     }
   }
)
```

Pre-populating the array also comes with the advantage that the most recent entry is always at the last position.

Comment: I thought about something similiar, but the problem is how to atomically increase pointer modulo 100 in mongodb?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable approach since the number of MAC versions is fixed. You should do the updates according to the docs linked in another answer - using `$slice` with `$push`.